# Как в VBA на вход функции, в качестве аргумента, подать экземпляр пользовательского класса?

Tags: access, vba

Class Tovar:

```
Public Code As Integer
Public Number As String
Public manufacturer As String
Public tovar_type As String
Public group As String
Public comment As String
```

Основной код:

```
Sub main()
    Dim mdb:    Set mdb = Access.CurrentDb
    Dim sSQL As String:     sSQL = "SELECT * FROM [SOTRAS]"
    Dim rst As Recordset:   Set rst = mdb.OpenRecordset(sSQL)
    Dim item As Tovar


    Do While Not rst.EOF
        Set item = New Tovar
        item.Code = rst.Fields("Êîä")
        item.manufacturer = rst.Fields("Ïðîèçâîäèòåëü")
        item.Number = rst.Fields("Íîìåð")
        item.tovar_type = rst.Fields("Òèï")
        add_tovar (item)
        rst.NextRecordset

    Loop

    rst.Close: Set rst = Nothing
    mdb.Close: Set mdb = Nothing


End Sub

Sub add_tovar(a As Tovar)
     .....
End sub
```

При запуске в строке add_tovar (item) вылетает ошибка:

Object doesn't support this property or method (Error 438)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался. Правильно использовать такие строки:

```
Call add_tovar(item)
rst.MoveNext
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы вызываете процедуру без возвращаемого значения, то в коде её вызов можно написать двумя способами:
`Call add_tovar(item)`
либо
`add_tovar item`

Answer (score 0):

определите тип в самом начале модуля

```
Type Tovar
   Price as Single
   Name as String
   TypeTovar as Byte
   Manufact as string
End Type


# затем 

Sub main()
    Dim mdb:    Set mdb = Access.CurrentDb
    Dim sSQL As String:     sSQL = "SELECT * FROM [SOTRAS]"
    Dim rst As Recordset:   Set rst = mdb.OpenRecordset(sSQL)
    Dim item As Tovar

# И все остальное
```